# ¿Como ajustar una aplicación vb6 dentro de un panel de mi formulario?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto en que tengo de abrir aplicaciones de vb6 i de otros proyectos vb.net, el echo es que he conseguido abrir las aplicaciones pero no encuentro la manera de que se ajusten en mi formulario, he intentado darle las midas de un picture box que tengo en el formulario principal, pero no ha resultado.
Las aplicaciones de vb.net con este metodo me funciona sin problemas, pero las de vb6 no.

La manera en que abro las aplicaciones es la siguiente.

```vb
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

Dim p() As Process
Private Function CheckIfRunning(pName As String) As Boolean
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName(pName)
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        ' Process is running
        Return True
    Else
        ' Process is not running
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub loadApp(filePath As String, parameters As String)
    Dim SplitPath() As String = Split(filePath, "\")
    Dim lastName As String = SplitPath.Last()
    SplitPath = Split(lastName, ".")
    Dim exeName As String = SplitPath(0)
    Try

        If Not CheckIfRunning(exeName) Then
            Dim proc1 As New Process()
            'Abrimos el ejecutable
            proc1.StartInfo.FileName = filePath
            proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters
            proc1.Start()
            proc1.WaitForInputIdle()

            Sleep(100)
            'Lo ajustamos en el panel "PanelExe"
            SetParent(proc1.MainWindowHandle, Me.PanelExe.Handle)
            SendMessage(proc1.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
            Dim lHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            Dim iPos As Int32 = 1
            dockForm(lHandle, picProg, False, IIf(m_tFuncions(iPos).Maximitzat, modc_API.eShowWindow.SHOWMAXIMIZED_eSW, modc_API.eShowWindow.SHOWNORMAL_eSW))
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: `Process.Start` inicia una aplicación,efectivamente. Lo que no entiendo es  como quieres que se ajuste a un formulario. Estas usando la api de windows para capturar la ventana y ponerla como hija de tu formulario o algo asi? Amplia tu pregunta para explicar mejor el proceso que estas siguiendo y como tratas de cambiar las medidas del formulario.

Comment: He actualizado la información, creo que ahora esta mas detallado..

Comment: podrias agregar que les pasa a las de vb6? hay que ver si windows para esas apliciones esta mandando esas interrupciones.